# Android: Change Textview Size of listview in runtime

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to change the textsize of the `TextView` which is used in `ListView` of my activity. But it shows error at runtime.

**My Activity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    settings();

    // Check Full Screen
    if (Fullscreen_Sett == true) {
        // hide statusbar of Android
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    // Content View
    setContentView(R.layout.tutoriallist_layout);

    // Backlight ON/OFF
    if (Backlight_Sett == true) {
        getWindow()
                .addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    }

    // ActionBar
    ActionBar ActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    ActionBar.setTitle("Tutorials");
    ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // load the animation
    animfade_in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.fade_in);
    animfade_out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.fade_out);
    // *********load the animation

    // ***********Set TextSize Of List
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tutoriallist_text_ID);
    tv.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), android.R.style.TextAppearance_Small);


    // Strings
    final String[] TutorialArray = getResources().getStringArray(
            R.array.Tutorial_Array);
    // List View Import
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.tutorial_listview);

    // Adding items to listview
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.tutoriallist_text,
            R.id.tutoriallist_text_ID, TutorialArray);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    if (Animation_Sett == true) {
        // Check Animation
        lv.startAnimation(animfade_in);
    }
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (arg2 == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tutorial",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }

    });

}
```

**MY XML FILE:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tutoriallist_text_ID"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/tutorialliststyle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:lines="2"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:typeface="monospace" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**LOG CAT :**

```
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060038 type #0x12 is not valid
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2144)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:853)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1158)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-01 11:10:34.744: E/AndroidRuntime(3826):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Note :** I have tried tv.settextsize(), and other too. But the bug it remains same...

Comment: Which error or exception it shows? Logcat Plz

Comment: updated with logcat/stacktrace

Comment: you want to get textview object which is not part of your view. if you want to change view size then you need to implement custom adapter for listview.

Comment: textview is in another XML and listview is in another XML right??

Comment: so you can't just get textview directly. you need custom adapter class and then update their.

Comment: how can i build that bro? any links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this help you:

Buddy i think you are getting this problem because you are using  `setContentView(R.layout.tutoriallist_layout);` as your main layout

And trying to instantiate a variable Of `TextView` which is another called: `R.layout.tutoriallist_text`

**Like:**

```
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tutoriallist_text_ID);
    tv.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), android.R.style.TextAppearance_Small);
```

Remove Those line and try to set attributes of that `TextView` in its `layout itself`...

**Edit:**

Comment these two lines and try again:

```
// ***********Set TextSize Of List
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tutoriallist_text_ID);
    tv.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), android.R.style.TextAppearance_Small);
```

**Edit 1:**

This is how you should create a Custom Adapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    Context context;
```

int layoutResourceId;
    ArrayList data = null;

```
public WeatherAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Weather[] data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    WeatherHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

    }
    else
    {
        row = counterView;
    }

    TextView tv = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tutoriallist_text_ID);

    tv.setTextAppearance(context, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Small);
    tv.setTextSize(specify size that you want);

    tv.setText(data.getIndex(position));

    return row;


   }

}
```

And Change this line your MyActivity:

```
    // Adding items to listview
     CustomAdapter  adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.tutoriallist_text, TutorialArray);
```

Comment: The main layout tutoriallist_layout has the listview , and using tutoriallist_text for using textview in listview ie, tutoriallist_text_ID

I have previously used this method still get the error :(

Comment: You are using `R.id.tutoriallist_text_ID` in the textview which is in `R.layout.tutoriallist_text` layout so try to comment those lines and try again buddy....

Comment: which lines should i comment bro? Sorry but i am a newbie . I am not clearly getting you.

I want to change the textsize at runtime according to the user.

Comment: i have a preference activity in which user sets the textsize of the text in listview. I am fetching the preferences and going to set the textsize according to the preferences. I dont want it to be static . If i mention that in xml it will be static

Comment: i know buddy what you want to do.. but you are referring that variable  outside the layout.. just try it once what i have suggested.. and let me know if current error are removed or not.. i will guide further..

Comment: Bro any solution? @ Bhavin

Comment: when i commented those lines the application worked properly without errors @Bhavin

Answer (score 0):

Keep a class variable,  which you can change:

```
private flot textSize = 15;
```

Alter views returned by adapter:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.tutoriallist_text,
            R.id.tutoriallist_text_ID, TutorialArray){
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            TextView tv = v.findViewById(R.id.tutoriallist_text_ID);
            tv.setTextSize(textSize);

            return v;
        }
 };
```

Change text size with:

```
textSize = 20;
adapter.notifyDatsetChanged();
```

Comment: it is showing error in eclipse intellisense is showing error bro @ S.D